# How to create all subarays form one array? SyntaxError: cannot use starred expression here

Tags: python

My code

```
a =[1,2,3]
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if j>=i:
            b=(*a[i:j+1])

print (b)
```

I got error

```
    b=(*a[i:j+1])
       ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: cannot use starred expression here
```

This was my desired output

```
[1]     
[2]     
[3]     
[1,2]       
[2,3]       
[1,2,3]
```

WHat should I change?

Comment: It would be `b=a[i:j+1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i think u should try this

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if j >= i:
           subarray = a[i:j+1]
           b.append(subarray)

 print(b)
```